# systemd stop service on package removal

Tags: services, systemd

I've made a *.deb with a service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Hello example service
Wants=nginx

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/hello

TimeoutStopSec=15
Restart=always
```

`postinst` script (doesn't affect anything except giving some error during the installation if used: `update-rc.d: error: initscript does not exist: /etc/init.d/hello`):

```
update-rc.d hello defaults
invoke-rc.d nginx reload
```

`prerm` debian script for it is:

```
invoke-rc.d hello stop
```

This script doesn't stop the service. It doesn't work even if launched manually. Returns 102 every time.

`systemctl stop` works fine for my service.

Somehow the `invoke-rc.d` works for the web server:

```
sudo invoke-rc.d nginx stop
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`invoke-rc.d`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/invoke-rc.d.8) command is for sysv init scripts (as its manpage says), not Upstart or systemd. Nginx still has a sysv init script (look for `init.d` in the [filelist](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/all/nginx-common/filelist)), which is probably why `invoke-rc.d` works for it (or seems to, anyway).

Even though the Debian guides use `invoke-rc.d`, on Ubuntu, prefer using the [`service`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/service.8) command. It is a wrapper script that can handle sysv init, Upstart and systemd files.

The [systemd documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/) recommends using `service` too:

> If your distribution removes SysV init scripts in favor of systemd
>   unit files typing `/etc/init.d/foobar start` to start a service will
>   not work, since the script will not be available. Use the more correct
>   `/sbin/service foobar start` instead, and your command will be
>   forwarded to systemd. Note that invoking the init script directly has
>   always been suboptimal since too much of the caller's execution
>   context (environment block, umask, resource limits, audit trails, ...)
>   ended up being inherited by the service, and invocation via
>   `/sbin/service` used to clean this up at least partially. Invocation
>   via /sbin/service works on both SysV and systemd systems. Also, LSB
>   only standardizes invocation via `/sbin/service` anyway. (Note that
>   some distributions ship both systemd unit files and SysV scripts for
>   the services. For these invoking the init scripts will work as
>   expected and the request be forwarded to systemd in any case.)

Of course, for Ubuntu, `service` is located at `/usr/sbin/service`.